# jQuery slideshow with separate div containing image specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have taken and essentially lightly modified a jQuery image slider to operate how I want, specifically one called: A Beautiful Apple-style Slideshow Gallery With CSS & jQuery.

I am currently attempting to link this slideshow to a separate div below that contains image specific text, I have achieved this in a very simple manor by hyper linking each thumbnail to load the content I want for each image.

Ideally I would like this to happen by using the next and previous controls for the slideshow but have tried multiple solutions without success. My current attempt loads the text for image 1 and image 2 but gets stuck from there onwards.

The html, css and JavaScript for my attempt can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/v9vf9/ (The result does not appear correctly as all my files are for the moment stored locally)

I am sure that what I am trying to achieve is not very complicated but seems to be beyond my ability, I appreciate any advice, help or solutions to succeed with this!! And look forwards to improving my knowledge.

Thank you in advance, Carl

Comment: I would probably try to put the text ( and it's own parent element i.e. `<div class="text">Text</div>`) into each `.slide` element and just position the text below the images properly. Since `#slides` has `overflow: hidden;` for a good reason, I would probably just raise the height of it so that the text can bee seen below the images. That way the text would slide with the images automatically.

Comment: Thank you @Lollero for your response, what you suggested does work perfectly with the slider and gives me image specific text with each slide but unfortunately as it is within the `#slides` div it appears above my thumbnails for the slider. This is why I was attempting to place the image specific text within it's own div, so that it can be positioned below the slider and appear separated although linked together through jQuery.

Comment: You can always do something like `#slides { position: relative; z-index: 5; } #thumbnail_parent_element { position: relative; z-index: 10; top: -50px; /* Or whatever value is needed to slide the humbnails into the right position asuming you want the text below the thumbnails like in your example */ }`

Comment: For example http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/Sw4y8/ ( in addition you may or may not need to put `#text { margin-top: 50px }` or something like that to leave space for the thumbnails to sit in. )

Comment: @Lollero I can't thank you enough for your help, such a simple solution I had overseen when trying to rework the javascript/jQuery, which quite frankly wasn't necessary. After taking a break from it last night, it all came together this morning, and is looking good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as suggested in the comments

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/Sw4y8/

It's a bit easier to put the text inside the animated slides so that they are animated with the images automatically and most importantly give `#slides` element a bigger height where the text can fit in.

HTML:

```
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/230" alt="" />
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="thumbnails">Thumbnails</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slides {
    height: 550px; /* or what ever amount is big enough to fit the text there too */
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

#thumbnails {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    top: -110px; 
}

.text { margin-top: 50px; /* for example if you want to give thumbnails room to sit above the text */ }
```